# Overlapping Trend Lines in scatterplots, R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, lm

I am trying to overlay multiple trend lines using the geom_smooth() in R. I currently have this code.

```
ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x=Displacement, y = Variable, color = Variable))
+ geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y = hp, col = "Power")) 
+ geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y = drat, col = "Drag Coef."))
```

(mtcars2 is the normalized form of mtcars)

Which give me this graph.
[image]

I am trying to use the geom_smooth(method='lm') to draw two trend lines for the the two variables. Any ideas?

(Bonus: I would also like to implement the 'shape=1' paramater to differentiate the varaibles if possible. The following method does not work)

```
geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y = hp, col = "Power", shape=2))
```

**Update**
I managed to do this.

```
ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x=Displacement, y = Variable, color = Variable)) 
+ geom_point(aes(x=disp, y = hp, col = "Power")) 
+ geom_point(aes(x=disp, y = mpg, col = "MPG")) 
+ geom_smooth(method= 'lm',aes(x=disp, y = hp, col = "Power"))
+ geom_smooth(method= 'lm',aes(x=disp, y = mpg, col = "MPG"))
```

It looks like this.

[image]

But this is an ugly piece of code. If anybody can make this code look prettier, it'd be great. Also, I have not yet been able to implement the 'shape=2' parameter.

Comment: How does `mtcars2` differ from `mtcars`?

Comment: I normalized the entire dataset. Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're making your life harder than it needs to be...you can pass in additional parameters into `aes()` such as `group` and `shape`.

I don't know if I got your normalization right, but this should give you enough to get going in the right direction:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#Do some normalization
mtcars$disp_norm <- with(mtcars, (disp - min(disp)) / (max(disp) -  min(disp)))
mtcars$hp_norm <- with(mtcars, (hp - min(hp)) / (max(hp) -  min(hp)))
mtcars$drat_norm <- with(mtcars, (drat - min(drat)) / (max(drat) -  min(drat)))

#Melt into long form
mtcars.m <- melt(mtcars, id.vars = "disp_norm", measure.vars = c("hp_norm", "drat_norm"))

#plot
ggplot(mtcars.m, aes(disp_norm, value, group = variable, colour = variable, shape = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Yielding:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked! However, I'd like a method where I can specifically choose the columns to use without creating a new table. (I know I am being very finicky, but I am trying to minimize code)

Comment: @krthkskmr - you can embed the `melt()` function within the call to `ggplot()` if you want. You'd then need to modify the `measure.vars` accordingly. However, there's a reason why 99% of `ggplot` examples start with  a call to `melt()`...and that's because you usually need to do some pre-processing of the data to get it into a `ggplot2` friendly format.

Comment: @krthkskmr - also, computer memory is cheap, writing overly dense code is not...sometimes breaking things out in steps is better :)

Comment: @krthkskmr - if this answers your question, can you hit the checkmark so other readers know this met your needs? Thanks!